# Enable magento caching for frontend only

Tags: magento, caching

can we enable caching for magento frontend only. I want to disable caching for backend and enable it for the frontend. Can we achieve this by making changes in core files?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

**Short answer:** not possible.

**Long answer:**
The thing that differentiates the backend and frontend from the app point of view, are the controllers.
The blocks and models are area agnostic.
And most caches are on blocks collections, configuration (which is also a model), webservices (which are not backend or frontend. they represent a different area).

An approach would be to check all the methods that load something from cache and let them pass through if you are on the admin area. But this will not work 100% either, because the configuration is loaded before the app knows if it's on backend or frontend areas.